# Is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of the lower limit topology $\mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Is the standard topology  on $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of the lower limit topology $\mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$?

Let $\mathcal{T_l}$ denote the lower-limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{T_s}$ denote the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

So let $\mathcal{B}$ be the basis for the lower-limit topology and $\mathcal{A}$ be the basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathcal{B} = \{ \ [a, b) \  | \ a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{ (a, b) \ | \ a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Now, there's a well known lemma that a topology $\mathcal{O}$ equals the collection of all unions of its basis elements.

So let $\mathcal{K}$ be an arbitrary sub-collection of $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{K} \subset \mathcal{A}$, and some $U \in \mathcal{T_s} = \bigcup_{K \in \mathcal{K}} K$, where $K = (a, b)$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

Again let $\mathcal{J}$ be an arbitrary sub-collection of $\mathcal{B}$, then $\mathcal{J} \subset \mathcal{B}$, and some $U \in \mathcal{T_l} = \bigcup_{J \in \mathcal{J}} J$, where $J = [a, b)$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

> **Lemma:** Every basis element $O \in \mathcal{O}$, is an element of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ it generates,
>   (I've put this lemma here as I use it in my argument below implicitly)

To show $\mathcal{T_s} \subset \mathcal{T_l}$, we need to show $U \in \mathcal{T_s} \implies U \in \mathcal{T_l}$.

But take $U = (a, b) \in \mathcal{T_s}$, then $U \not\in \mathcal{T_l}$  because no union of sets $[a, b) \in \mathcal{B}$ will equal $(a, b)$. It is clear that $(a, b) \subset [a, b)$, but $(a, b) \in \mathcal{T_s} \not\Rightarrow (a, b) \in \mathcal{T_l}$ *(in fact $\mathcal{T_l}$ does not contain any sets of the form $(a, b)$, correct me if I'm wrong please)*. So how can it be true that $\mathcal{T_s} \subset \mathcal{T_l}$?

Comment: You must show that $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal T_l$.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong that $(a,b)$ cannot be written as a union of sets of the form $[a,b)$. You can write

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b).$$

edit: as has been pointed out, this is under the "convention" that $[a,b)=\varnothing$ if $a\geqslant b$. If you don't like defining things this way, then all you need to do is choose an integer $N>\frac{1}{b-a}$, so that $a+\frac{1}{N}<b$; then we have

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b).$$

Comment: What happens then if $(a, b) = (0, \frac{1}{2})$? You would have to change the indexing set for the union then surely? And we can always arbitrarily change the indexing set for the union because our basis $\mathcal{B}$ consists of *all* $[a, b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ correct?

Comment: @Perturbative that's all a matter of convention on what the interval $[1,\frac{1}{2})$ is. Personally, I would say an interval $(a,b)$ is the empty set if $a>b$.

Comment: Otherwise, you'd just need to choose $N$ such that $a+\frac{1}{N}<b$, which certainly exists. Then $(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Every set $(a,b)$ is open in the lower limit topology: if $x \in (a,b)$ then $x \in [x,b) \subseteq (a,b)$, so $x$ is an interior point of $(a,b)$. Or equivalently, $(a,b) = \cup\{[x,b): x \in (a,b)\}$, so $(a,b)$ is a union of lower limit open sets.